# Passing --env.prod Value to Webpack 4 with Visual Studio 2017 SPA

Tags: angular, webpack, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to upgrade my SPA to Angular 6 (which is based on the Visual Studio 2017 SPA).

I in my `package.json` i have the following;

```
{
  "name": "mjyproject",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.7",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/hammerjs": "2.0.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/mousetrap": "1.6.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "agm-core": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "ajv": "^6.5.2",
    "angular-modal-gallery": "5.7.1",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "angular2-useful-swiper": "5.0.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "aws-sdk": "2.276.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "^2.2.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "3.0.0",
    "mousetrap": "1.6.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.5",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "swiper": "3.4.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "latest-version": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Then I have upgraded the `webpack.config.js` file to the following;

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
//const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;
const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader', 'angular2-router-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot.browser.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new AotPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.browser.module#AppModule'),
                exclude: ['./**/*.server.ts']
            })
        ])
    });

    // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot.server.ts' },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                name: './vendor'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new AotPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.server.module#AppModule'),
                exclude: ['./**/*.browser.ts']
            })
        ]),
        output: {
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```

This has been upgraded to use the `AngularCompilerPlugin`.

Now I can run

`webpack --config ./webpack.config.js`

however, in webpack 4 I cannot see how to integrate the new `mode: 'production'` to the web.config.js, per the link for the documentation

[webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/)

I assume I could add;

```
mode: isDevBuild ? 'development : 'production',
```

However I have the following issues;

1. How do I pass the `env.prod` to the `webpack` command
2. Do I then just need to ammend the .csproj exec scripts to reflect the change when I publish? (so that it publish with production builds as opposed to the development build).

Comment: `webpack --config ./webpack.config.js --env.prod`

Comment: When I try this though the command errors.

Comment: you better refactor and rely on process.env.NODE_ENV being production or development. Way better than using env from webpack